# clang cannot parse sources that includes libstdc++ (gcc4.4)

Tags: gcc, clang, libstdc++

i have recently compiled new clang(3.1 now), and tried to use it for parsing my project, however it fails at parsing standard libraries/includes... for example i see following errors:

/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstddef:51:9: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
or
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:71:3: error: unknown type name 'template'

Obviously clang cannot parse this files, but these are standard libstc files ..what should i do with this?

Comment: You are using `clang++` I hope?

Comment: well.. i have misinformed all slightly ..i was using libclang. And yes, the problem was, V vs C++  - if you use c++, you better force the parser the c++ language, because, it sometimes excpect c code instead of c++.

Comment: majkl: why not answer your own question and accept it. Then this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have my own answer:
 First, i hadn't introduced properly the problem. I was using libclang library, not the compiler itself.
 Second the solution is to force always c++ language, when you parse c++ code, since the parser itself sometimes decides, that he is parsing c code, even if its c++ code.

the solution is, to pass -xc++ argument to the parser.